# setting classpath in ant build

Tags: java, ant, jar, classpath, manifest.mf

my classpath defined in the MANIFEST.MF files references to a dir with all the required jars in it, and I would like to add a refference to a jar that is not located inside that directory. This jar should be loaded by the application from the path that was inside the MANIFEST.MF file.

something like this:

Class-Path: lib/something.jar lib/anything.jar
           lib/m16.jar lib/apache.jar

and the wanted is like this:

Class-Path: lib/something.jar lib/anything.jar
           lib/m16.jar some/other/path/lib/apache.jar

Thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Did you try with absolute paths if that's practicable?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but one simple option would be to save a copy of your `MANIFEST.MF` file in your project and then amend the classpath so that it meets your requirements. Then you can specify the specific manifest to use in the `<jar>` entry of your build file, something like this:

```
<jar destfile="./bin/MyProject.jar"
    basedir="."
    manifest="./path_to_manifests/MANIFEST.MF"/>
```